Draw the Flag of Greenland
The flag of Greenland consists of two red sections and two white sections. I'll provide a diagram below, but also give a textual description. The background of the flag is a rectangle that is 18 units wide and 12 units tall. The bottom half of the background is red, and the top half is white. There's a circle in the middle with a radius of 4 units, with the colors reversed: the top half is red, and the bottom half is white. The circle is centered vertically, but not horizontally: There are 3 units of space between the circle and the left edge of the flag, and 7 units of space between the circle and the right edge of the flag.

Your challenge is to generate this flag in some capacity -- be that displaying it on the screen, or saving it as an image file. Retrieving it from an online resource or outputting the emoji is banned. The red color does not have to exactly match the color in the image above, as long as it is obviously red. (I couldn't actually find conclusive information about what shade of red it's supposed to be -- different sites gave conflicting answers.)

what is the minimum size of the flag?

@nyxbird bbrk's said in chat that the flag should be at least 18x12 pixels but that should be edited into the question.

I mean, it’s not really possible to meet the spec as written with smaller than 12x18

By the way, the term in heraldry when a charge on a field has its colors reversed from those of the field, like the circle on the flag, is "counterchanged." I just thought I'd throw that out there.

But this isn't heraldry, it's vexillology

@roblogic – it's vexing alright

Desmos, 12 bytes
(r-4)sinθ<0

Try it on Desmos!
As is somewhat standard with Desmos graphical-output, this uses the graph settings to frame/colour the image appropriately and remove background settings, which isn't included in the byte count. r-4 is negative within the circle of radius 4 around the origin, and sinθ is negative below the x-axis, so the image is red where exactly one of these is negative.
An alternate that only draws the part of the image in frame, for 33 bytes (leading newline is necessary to paste properly):

(xx+yy-16)y<0\{-7<x<11\}\{y>-6\}

Try it on Desmos!

I'm not sure how I feel about this one. I'll take your word that it's standard for Desmos to frame the image using non-byte-counted code, but in this case the framing is responsible for one of the key criteria of the output, namely the horizontal positioning of the circle. I'd like the answer better if it cut off the red region at the edges of the flag, leaving a white background on all sides.

@DLosc Fair enough. I've added a version that only draws that part of the image, and I do agree this is bending the rules a bit.

ZX Spectrum Basic, 140 bytes
  10 DIM a$(PI*PI): FOR i=SGN PI
 TO PI: PRINT BRIGHT SGN PI; INK
 VAL "2";a$: NEXT i: FOR i=SGN P
I TO PI: PRINT BRIGHT SGN PI; IN
K VAL "7"; PAPER VAL "2";a$: NEX
T I: LET a=VAL "15": FOR i=-a TO
 a: FOR j=-a TO a: PLOT INK VAL
"8"; INVERSE i*i+j*j>VAL "255";i
+VAL "28",j+VAL "152": NEXT j: N
EXT i

The above shows how the program lists in 48K mode or with the LIST command. Explanation: 24 rows and 72 columns of pixels are drawn in bright white with a red foreground, then another 24 rows are drawn in red with a bright white foreground. A solid circle is then drawn at the appropriate position; INK 8 avoids changing the foreground colour, so the circle takes on the colour of the two rectangles. VAL and PI are used to avoid integer constants which would otherwise cost six extra bytes each.


I like seeing retro come to play

SVG, 60 58bytes
Tested in Chrome and Edge. 1 byte saved thanks to Neil and 1 byte of whitespace deleted.


<svg><path d="M0 30h55a20 20 0 1 0 0 1h35v29H0"fill="red">



Drawn at 5 times the scale in the question (maybe I can go lower for less bytes.)
The trick here is that the circle is not quite complete. There is a tiny gap in the white section on the right hand side. We start at centre left, move to the right of the circle, complete an arc with nominal 0 degree (or with large arc flag set, 360 degree) rotation (with a tiny vertical offset to let SVG know the correct circle orientation), move to the centre right of the flag, the bottom rightand finally to the bottom left. The path is not explicitly closed but this works in most browsers.
SVG, 56 54 48 bytes
Drawn at the scale in the question, which apparently is the min allowable. This version incorporates all golfs from emanresu, shaggy and ccprog and still works in Chrome and Edge despite the nonstandard syntax.


<svg><path d=M0,6h11a4,4,0,100,.1h7v6H0 fill=red




The smaller version renders fine in Safari 18 (iOS) as well, but the errors cover up the bottom part of the larger version.

The trailing H0 trick works on your first answer too to save a byte.

The best I could do with perfect rendering was <svg><path d="M0,6H11A4,4,0,0,0,3,6a4,4,0,0,0,8,0h7v6H0"fill="red">.

@Neil Thanks, H0 would save a byte on the larger version, but I decided not to edit to avoid invalidating Bbrk's comment. Your perfect rendering comes in at 67 bytes. The gap in the circle per my method can be made arbitrarily small (say 0.0001) but there does have to be a theoretical gap so SVG knows where to put the centre of the circle.

I have now updated per Neil's comment. I've made another change H55->h55 to correct what I thought might be an error. I later realised this makes no difference since the move was from x=0 anyway.

.1 instead of 0.1 in the second one seems to work.

50: <svg><path d="M0 6h11a4 4 0 1 00 .1h7v6H0"fill=red

48: <svg><path d=M0,6h11a4,4,0,100,.1h7v6H0 fill=red

GFA-Basic 3.51 (Atari ST), 43 bytes
A manually edited listing in .LST format. All lines end with CR, including the last one.
SET 15,1792
PC 35,30,20
GR 3
PB 0,30,90,60

Expanded and commented
SETCOLOR 15,1792 ! set color #15 to 0x700 = red
PCIRCLE 35,30,20 ! draw a filled circle of radius 20 at (35,30)
GRAPHMODE 3      ! set the drawing mode to XOR
PBOX 0,30,90,60  ! draw a filled rectangle from (0,30) to (90,60)

Output


I just noticed, is there one extra red pixel on the far left?

Yes, it seems like PBOX is a bit buggy in XOR mode. Maybe the rectangle boundary is drawn twice -- or at least partly.

TinyAPL, 43 bytes
⎕DisplayImage{1⍪2⌿0>⍵×8-|⍵⊕15}◠13-⊕⍆¨⍳24‿36

Try online
Many thanks to @emanresu A for -25 with a change in approach.
Result:

Explanation:
⎕DisplayImage{1⍪2⌿0>⍵×8-|⍵⊕15}◠13-⊕⍆¨⍳24‿36­⁡​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
                                  ⊕⍆¨⍳24‿36  ⍝ ‎⁡complex number matrix from 1+i to 24+36i
                               13-           ⍝ ‎⁢13 minus that, i.e. matrix from 12-i to -11-36i
             {               }◠              ⍝ ‎⁣for each element of the matrix
                         ⍵⊕15                ⍝ ‎⁤add 15i, i.e. matrix from 12+14i to -11-21i
                        |                    ⍝ ‎⁢⁡magnitude
                      8-                     ⍝ ‎⁢⁢8 minus that
                    ⍵×                       ⍝ ‎⁢⁣multiplied by the original element
                  0>                         ⍝ ‎⁢⁤is negative?
              1⍪2⌿                           ⍝ ‎⁣⁡[1, x, x] -> [1, 0, 0] (red) or [1, 1, 1] (white)
⎕DisplayImage                                ⍝ ‎⁣⁢show image in editor


Created with the help of Luminespire.

I think it would be one byte shorter to double the size -- +1 from changing 6‿18 to 12‿36, but then -2 from changing 6.5‿7.5 to 13‿15. The squared radius changes from 16 to 64, but that's the same length either way.

Building on bbrk's using complex numbers with ⎕DisplayImage⦅1⋄⍪⋄⍪⍨⦆◠~⍢{⍵⌿⍨⍥,{8≥|(⊕⍆⍵)-13⊕15}¨⍳⍴⍵}∨12‿36⍴⍤∞‿0 1‿0 saves another byte (edit: 65 with ⎕DisplayImage⦅1⋄⍪⋄⍪⍨⦆◠~⍢{⍵⌿⍨⍥,{8≥|⍵-13⊕15}¨⊕⍆¨⍳⍴⍵}∨12‿36⍴⍤∞‿0 1‿0)

In fact you don't even need the dfn, ⎕DisplayImage⦅1⋄⍪⋄⍪⍨⦆◠~⍢{⍵⌿⍨⍥,8≥|(13⊕15)-⊕⍆¨⍳⍴⍵}∨12‿36⍴⍤∞‿0 1‿0 for 63

⎕DisplayImage⦅1⋄⍪⋄⍪⍨⦆◠{0>⍵×8-|⍵+⊕15}¨13-⊕⍆¨⍳24‿36 for 49

And some variation of ⎕DisplayImage{1⍪2⌿0>⍵×8-|⍵⊕15}¨13-⊕⍆¨⍳24‿36 should be shorter but I don't understand the array model enough to know quite what's wrong

@emanresuA replace the Each on the dfn with an On Scalars, that way the colors are added as a new axis instead of a new depth. I'll edit the answer later, but thanks a lot for all the outgolfing. I had an idea of doing something similar but I had to go to bed(:

MS SQL Server - Management Studio, 483 bytes
CREATE TABLE #R(P GEOMETRY)
DECLARE @c geometry=geometry::Point(0,0,0).STBuffer(4)
DECLARE @t geometry='POLYGON((-7 6,11 6,11 0,-7 0,-7 6))'
DECLARE @b geometry='POLYGON((-7 -6,11 -6,11 0,-7 0,-7 -6))'
DECLARE @e geometry='POLYGON((0 0,1e-9 1e-9,0 1e-9,0 0))'
DECLARE @i INT=1
WHILE @i<802 BEGIN INSERT INTO #R(P)VALUES(@e);SET @i=@i+1;END
INSERT INTO #R(P)VALUES(@t.STDifference(@c).STUnion(@b.STIntersection(@c))),(@t.STIntersection(@c).STUnion(@b.STDifference(@c)))
SELECT*FROM #R

More of a hot pink than red:

640 bytes to get a nicer red by overlapping the geometries:
CREATE TABLE #R(P GEOMETRY)
DECLARE @c geometry=geometry::Point(0,0,0).STBuffer(4)
DECLARE @t geometry='POLYGON((-7 6,11 6,11 0,-7 0,-7 6))'
DECLARE @b geometry='POLYGON((-7 -6,11 -6,11 0,-7 0,-7 -6))'
DECLARE @e geometry='POLYGON((0 0,1e-9 1e-9,0 1e-9,0 0))'
DECLARE @i INT=1
WHILE @i<802 BEGIN INSERT INTO #R(P)VALUES(@e);SET @i=@i+1;END
INSERT INTO #R(P)VALUES(@t.STDifference(@c).STUnion(@b.STIntersection(@c))),(@t.STIntersection(@c).STUnion(@b.STDifference(@c)))
SET @i=0
WHILE @i<5 BEGIN INSERT INTO #R(P)VALUES(@e);SET @i=@i+1;END
INSERT INTO #R(P)VALUES(@t.STIntersection(@c).STUnion(@b.STDifference(@c)))
SELECT*FROM #R



Uiua, 39 30 chars
-:1⋯×6=⊞⊃(>4⌵ℂ-5.5|>5)⇡12-7⇡18

Pad Link

Uiua, 29 chars - More faded red
-⋯×6=⊞⊃(>4⌵ℂ-5.5|>5)⇡12-7⇡18η


Red is faded since it is the color [1, pi/4-1, pi/4-1] = [1, 0.214, 0.214] which is probably red enough.

You can get 29 chars with normal colors by using my method of ∵[1.] and using ≠ instead of =: pad

Uiua, 29 24 21 bytes
∵[1.]⊂¬⇌.≤4⌵⊞ℂ⇡6-7⇡18

Try it: Uiua pad
Golfed 24 -> 21 bytes thanks to Mousetail.
Output, upscaled:

I used the circle equation \$ \sqrt{(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2} \le r \$, with 6 and 7 substituted for \$ h \$ and \$ k \$, and \$ r^2 \$ being inlined as 16. Rather than squaring and square rooting, Mousetail suggested using the magnitude of the complex number x+yi, saving 3 bytes. Instead of drawing the whole circle and inverting half of it, I drew half of the circle and joined on top a reversed and inverted copy.
Multiplying each number except for the leading one by some fixed factor will give the flag at a higher resolution. Here's the output of multiplying each by ten: Uiua pad


21 chars

C64 BASIC, 210 bytes
1pO53265,187:pO53272,24
2fOy=0to199:fOx=0to319:pO1024+x*y/62,18
3a=8192+int(y/8)*320+int(x/8)*8+(yaN7)
4c=abs(((116-x)^2+(100-y)^2>4356)=(y>100)):b=7-(xaN7):q=pE(a)
5pOa,(qor2^b)*(1-c)+(qaN(nO2^b))*c:nE:nE
6gO6

Draws the flag in high-res graphics mode in about 4 hours.

Try in emulator

I should've expected a 6502 processor to take 4 hours to render this LOL

@Joao-3, can't really blame the 6502. It's really a hideously inefficient way to do this :)

[Python 3 + pycairo], 199190 bytes
Golfed 9 bytes thanks to @musava-ribica and different import
from cairo import*
x=Context(SVGSurface("g",18,12))
s=x.set_source_rgb
f=x.fill
r=7,6,4,0,3.14
s(1,1,1)
x.paint()
s(1,0,0)
x.rectangle(0,6,18,6)
x.arc_negative(*r)
f()
s(1,1,1)
x.arc(*r)
f()



A lot of room for improvement here. Instead of defining variable i, pass the SVGSurface directly. You don't need parentheses for tuple constant: r=7,6,4,0,3.14 suffices.

AWK, 221 bytes
func p(a,b){for(;a--;)printf(b?"\033[97m":"\033[31m")"█"}{n=$1;r=n/2;for(y=-r+2;y++<r-2;){g=n*y<r;p(int(2*r/3),g)
for(x=-r;x++<r;)x*x+y*y*4<r*r?p(1,!g):p(1,g);p(n,g);print"";if(!y){p(int(2*r/3))p(n-1,1)p(n+1);print""}}}

Fixed so it should now scale without getting into an infinite loop:
awk 'func p(a,b){for(;a--;)printf(b?"\033[97m":"\033[31m")"█"}{n=$1;r=n/2;for(y=-r+2;y++<r-2;){g=n*y<r;p(int(2*r/3),g)
for(x=-r;x++<r;)x*x+y*y*4<r*r?p(1,!g):p(1,g);p(n,g);print"";if(!y){p(int(2*r/3))p(n-1,1)p(n+1);print""}}}' <<< 30



This is great. Can you save some bytes by hard-coding the width and height?

you can remove the newline before BEGIN.

tying into what @Jordan said, you can remove ;w=...d=...m" and replace printf(...) with printf"\033["b*66+31"m█"

the ?1:0 after g=n*y<r can be removed as well

PNG, 112 bytes
Hand-drawn pixel art compressed by ImageOptim.

00000000: 8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452  .PNG........IHDR
00000010: 0000 0012 0000 000c 0802 0000 00e0 707a  ..............pz
00000020: eb00 0000 3749 4441 5478 0163 f84f 16a0  ....7IDATx.c.O..
00000030: 92b6 0b3c c670 845f 1ba6 1ec2 3a19 d0f4  ...<.p._....:...
00000040: 6022 aa6a c325 8ddf 380a b4c1 117e 3d98  `".j.%..8....~=.
00000050: da10 88a0 1e84 365c 88fa da00 d530 b520  ......6\.....0. 
00000060: 0d47 c1d5 0000 0000 4945 4e44 ae42 6082  .G......IEND.B`.


You can get 62 bytes with lossless webp compression. base64 encoded: UklGRjYAAABXRUJQVlA4TCkAAAAvEcACAFUoaNvIIXD86d7vBeE9xHPS/wlI3o2xYbhkegF/avGEkfXO2w==

107 bytes for an HTML version: jsfiddle

Python 3.10 + Turtle, 184 bytes
The script draws the flag with minimum dimensions 18x12.
from turtle import*
x=setx
b=begin_fill
e=end_fill
def c():circle(4,180);e()
setup(18,12)
ht()
color(1,0,0)
b()
x(-6)
x(-9)
sety(-6)
x(9)
sety(0)
x(2)
seth(90)
c()
color(1,1,1)
b()
c()

Try it online!

Result:


SVG, 127 125 bytes


<svg viewBox=".5,0,9,6"><path fill="red" d="M10,0V6H0V0"/><path fill="#FFF" d="M0,0V3H2A2,2,0,116,3A2,2,0,112,3h9V0"/></svg>



Expanded:
<svg viewBox=".5,0,9,6">
  <path fill="red" d="
    M 10,0
    V 6
    H 0
    V 0
  "/>
  <path fill="#FFF" d="
    M 0,0
    V 3
    H 2
    A 2,2 0 1 1 6,3
    A 2,2 0 1 1 2,3
    h 9
    V 0
  "/>
</svg>


This doesn’t even work for me (Safari on iOS 18). I see half a red circle and then a large error.

@Bbrk24 It works for me in Safari on iOS 18. https://i.sstatic.net/viws4Eo7.png

I just tried again, and actually, I reported the wrong browser! it works fine in both Safari and Chrome, but errors in Firefox. Since when are they different? I thought all browsers on iOS had to use the same engine. In any case, I’m not sure how to upload an image to a comment.

@Bbrk24 I just cheat by uploading it in a draft answer and then copying the URL.

That's one problem with SVG is the inconsistent implementations. I've been trying to use them (not this one) in MS Word documents and am getting different results. I believe you can also omit the quotes (-10 bytes), but there's less and less implementations that support that.

Shadertoy (GLSL), 99 bytes
void mainImage(out vec4 a,vec2 b){a=vec4(1,vec3(b.y<225.^^distance(vec2(262.5,225.),b)<150.?0:1));}

Shadertoy link.


Arguably cheating since the shader has to be run at just the right resolution (450x675) for the image to be correct, which Shadertoy doesn't even support, but I was too excited about the XOR trick to not share :)

Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! The 1.0s, second 255.0 and 0.0 can just be 1, 255 and 0 since ints are fine there, and the 150.0 and other 225.0 can just be 150. and 225. Also, you might want to put the golfed code in the shadertoy link just to demonstrate that it's the same as the less-golfed version.

@emanresuA thank you for the tips! I didn't realize I could left some of those as ints, didn't know about the shortened float notation either. The golfed version appears on shadertoy when clicking on the character count at the bottom of the editor, so I imagine it's OK?

TinyAPL, 43 39 bytes*
⎕DisplayImage 1∘⍪⍤⍪⍨◠⊖⍤~⊸⍪4≥⍉|7-18⊕⊞⍥⍳6

Try it: TinyAPL REPL
-4 thanks to RubenVerg for telling me that some parentheses were unnecessary and suggesting a clever way to get around parentheses in (⍳6).
This is based on my Uiua solution.
Explanation:
18⊕⊞⍥⍳6 - the 18x6 table of complex numbers (0..17)+(0..5)i.
⍉|7- - subtract the real parts from 7, get the magnitude (\$ \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \$) of each, and transpose. This gives a 6x18 grid where each cell contains its distance to (0, 7).
4≥ - Is each distance greater than or equal to 4? This gives a zero for pixels in the circle and a one for pixels outside.
⊖⍤~⊸⍪ - Prepend a reversed, inverted copy of the array. This adds on the top half of the flag, yielding a 12x18 boolean array. The booleans still have to be mapped to colors.
1∘⍪⍤⍪⍨◠ - To each value, prepend a one and itself, giving a length-3 array. This maps zeroes to 1,0,0 and ones to 1,1,1, which correspond to red and white respectively in RGB colors. The result is a 12x18x3 array representing the image.
⎕DisplayImage - Self-explanatory.

*Encoded with 1 byte per character using (⎕Import"std:sbcs")→Encode.

⎕DisplayImage{1⍪2⌿⍵}◠(⊖⍤~)⊸⍪4≥|(⍳6)⊕⊞7-⍳18 for -1

@emanresuA Thanks, but I realized I actually don't need a lot of the parentheses I put, so what I have is shorter.

|(⍳6)⊕⊞7-⍳18 → ⍉|7-18⊕⊞⍥⍳6 for -1

Chipmunk Basic, 252 225 228 bytes
graphics 0:k(0):graphics fillrect 0,60,180,120:t=pi/2
for i=t to t*3 step.002:k(0):p(i):k(99):p(i+pi):next
sub p(a):x=70+sin(a)*40:graphics moveto x,60:graphics lineto x,60+cos(a)*40:return
sub k(c):graphics color 99,c,c:return

Install v368b202 (MacOS) to test - the online compiler doesn't do graphics. Corrected artefacts by filling the semi-circles with vertical lines instead of radiating from the centre. Circle is now centred at (70,60) - was incorrectly placed at (90,60) before.
Description
1: k(0) :set colour to red, draw the lower rectangle, let t = π/2
2: loop from right of circle (angle t) to left (t*3)
     k(0):p(i) :red line at angle i
     k(99):p(i+pi) :white line at angle i+π
3: sub p(a) :draw a line segment from (90,60) (x,60) to (x,y) given by sin() and cos()
4: sub k(c) :change pen colour using chipmunk basic's RGB range of (0-100)
Ungolfed prototype version


Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 23 bytes
"GL"~CountryData~"Flag"



Doesn't this retrieve the flag from an online resource, which is specifically banned?

@MontyWild I don't really know what exactly is behind this function. If anybody knows, please let us know.

This ought to be pretty easy to test: Disconnect from the internet, then try to access a flag you haven’t accessed before.

@Jordan I use online mathematica right now. But I remember those being packages. The question is what exactly is this function returning.

Plaintext 8 bytes:

@ADJenks I also specifically banned using the emoji

@Bbrk24 ha, yeah I know. I was just joking of course, which is why it's a comment on a questionably valid answer. I would have posted it as an answer if I thought it was valid.

@ADJenks usually you put joke answers as a comment to the question itself, not on a random answer. comments of solutions on a specific answer are taken as a suggested golf. (incidentally, I think this answer should be valid; mathematica just happens to have a builtin for everything)

@guest4308 I added it here as a jocular comment to reflect specifically on the absurdity of this answer. Thank you though.

Python 3, 127 bytes
This uses XOR for the alternating colors, and a distance formula for the circle, and some ANSI codes for the color changes.  Changing to black after every character instead of when done with a line saved 2 bytes.  I could probably cheat a couple more bytes by finding resolutions that would let me omit decimals, maybe saving another 4 bytes but there would probably be some rounding errors.  The solution as it stands can be adjusted for other resolutions.
for y in range(12):
 for x in range(18):print("\033[4"+("7"if(y<6)^((x-6.5)**2+(y-5.5)**2<16)else"1"),end="m \033[0m")
 print()



C (GCC), 101 100 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @ceilingcat

i;main(k){for(puts("P6 18 12 1");i<648;putchar(i<324^i/54*(i/54-11)+k*(k-13)<-57|i++%3<1))k=i%54/3;}

Attempt This Online!
Outputs a PPM image.
Result: 
